# Ajax Modal Popup Extender With Repeater

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I'm working with the Ajax ModalPopupExtender inside of a Repeater, but it is not showing because of some javascript error and other stuff.  Could someone provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The way I have done this :

1. Place the ModalPopupExtender outside (after) of the repeater control.
2. Add a Button that will act as a 'fake' Target for the ModalPopupExtender, place this outside(after) of the repeater. Use 'Style="display: none"' to hide the button from the user. No OnClick event should be bound to this button.
3. Place the ModalPopupExtender's target Panel outside of the Repeater.
4. Within the repeater's item template add a linkbutton with an OnClick, using the linkbutton allows you to use the commandArgument, which can be bound to a DataBinder - say for a record ID
5. In the codebehind create a sub that handles the onclick event for the linkbutton in the repeater. If needed, do a directCast of the sender object to a linkbutton so you have access to the commandArgument.
6. Populate the ModalPopupExtender target Panel appropriately
7. Do a ModalPopupExtender.show()

**HTML**

```
<ul id="Repeater">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMain" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <span class="RepeaterHeader">
      <li>
        Edit
      </li>
    </span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li class="RptLeadItemEdit">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"
           CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>' 
           OnClick="OpenMPEEdit" />
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
<asp:Button ID="MpeFakeTarget" runat="server" 
     CausesValidation="False" Style="display:none" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeEdit" runat="server" 
     TargetControlId="MpeFakeTarget" 
     PopupControlID="pnlEdit" 
     OkControlID="btCloseMPE" 
     BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" />
<asp:Panel CssClass="ModalPanel" runat="server" ID="pnlEdit">
  EDIT LEAD
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="MPETEST"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btCloseMPE" text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Protected Sub OpenMPEEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim wLink As New LinkButton
        wLink = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
        MPETEST.Text = "ID = " & wLink.CommandArgument
        mpeEdit.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this and the linkbutton click does nothing, it's not entering the sub's code. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought: have you changed the '<asp:LinkButton ID='btEdit'....' line? The only thing I can think of is that the OnClick event is not being bound.

Comment: thanks for the code. I have been working on an aspnet photo app and this functionality has moved my project to the next step. thanks again. up vote for this one.